# Stored procedure Date From and Date To

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure for filtering orders. Basically the users have the option of filtering the order by date from and date to. So they can do search via date from, date to or use both if it makes sense?

Anyhow here is my SQL Server stored procedure so far

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CN_GetOrderItemByCustID]
    @CustomerID int,
    @OrderItemWRClass varchar(max) = NULL,
    @OrderItemSKUName varchar(50) = NULL,
    @OrderItemDateFrom Datetime,
    @OrderItemDateTo Datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF DATEDIFF(d, @OrderItemDateFrom, '01/01/1970') = 0 
       SET @OrderItemDateFrom = null 
    IF DATEDIFF(d, @OrderItemDateTo, '01/01/1970') = 0 
       SET @OrderItemDateTo = null 

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        COM_OrderItem.OrderItemID, COM_Order.OrderID, 
        COM_Order.OrderDate, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemUnitCount, 
        COM_OrderItem.OrderItemStatus, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUNAME,
        COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUID
    FROM 
        COM_OrderItem
    INNER JOIN 
        COM_Order ON COM_Order.OrderID = COM_OrderItem.OrderItemOrderID
    WHERE  
        COM_Order.OrderCustomerID = @CustomerID 
        OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemWRClass LIKE @OrderItemWRClass + '%' 
        OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUName LIKE @OrderItemSKUName + '%'
        OR CONVERT(VARCHAR, COM_Order.OrderDate, 120) LIKE @OrderItemDateFrom + '%' 
    ORDER BY 
        COM_Order.OrderDate DESC
```

However I am not sure on how to put the date from (`OrderItemDateFrom`) and date to (`OrderItemDateTo`) in the final SQL statement?

Should I be using `OR CONVERT(VARCHAR, COM_Order.OrderDate, 120) LIKE @OrderItemDateFrom + '%'` -- which gives me an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know in a normal SQL query I would use `Between OrderItemDateFrom and OrderItemDateTo`

Thanks

Comment: @Thierry I am not sure how that link helps me?

Comment: apologies, wrong thread. Will delete it in a sec.

Comment: @Kevin use `BETWEEN` for much cleaner query

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CN_GetOrderItemByCustID]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CustomerID int,
@OrderItemWRClass varchar(max) = NULL,
@OrderItemSKUName varchar(50) = NULL,
@OrderItemDateFrom Datetime,
@OrderItemDateTo Datetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF DATEDIFF(d,@OrderItemDateFrom,'01/01/1970')=0 SET @OrderItemDateFrom = '01/01/1970';
IF DATEDIFF(d,@OrderItemDateTo,'01/01/1970')=0 SET @OrderItemDateTo = '31/12/2199';

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT COM_OrderItem.OrderItemID, COM_Order.OrderID, COM_Order.OrderDate, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemUnitCount, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemStatus, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUNAME,
COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUID
FROM COM_OrderItem
INNER JOIN COM_Order ON COM_Order.OrderID = COM_OrderItem.OrderItemOrderID
WHERE COM_Order.OrderCustomerID = @CustomerID OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemWRClass LIKE @OrderItemWRClass + '%' OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUName LIKE @OrderItemSKUName + '%'
OR (COM_OrderDate>=@OrderItemDateFrom && COM_OrderDate<=@OrderItemDateTo ) 
ORDER BY COM_Order.OrderDate DESC
```

Try it . It should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However one more thing should I be casting or converting the COM_OrderDate field into a varchar? As the values are stored with time e.g. '2016-03-08 10:40:12.477' where as I am only passing the date. Thanks

Comment: @Kevin It should not matter use '2016-03-08' directly

Comment: @Kevin Did u try ? Please mention if you encountered any error.

Comment: I am getting @OrderItemDateFrom requires value when I run the query. I see you have removed `SET @OrderItemDateFrom = null`?

Comment: @Kevin You can implement assigning value at your backend before you call your stored procedure that is based on user's input , if he doesn't supply FROM date set it to ='01/01/1970' and if he doesn't supply TO date set it to ='12/12/2199' and if he doesn't supply both the dates assign values to both of them . Now pass dates to stored procedure.AND finally remove both DATEDIFF Statements from the query

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be simplified a little by allowing NULL values for `@OrderItemDateFrom` and `@OrderItemDateTo`. Also, if filters values and column values are all `DATETIME`s, you should try to compare directly to allow indexes usages (if any applied on the DATETIME column):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CN_GetOrderItemByCustID]
    @CustomerID int,
    @OrderItemWRClass varchar(max) = NULL,
    @OrderItemSKUName varchar(50) = NULL,
    @OrderItemDateFrom Datetime = NULL, -- TODO: change caller to not provide parameter, or leave it to null
    @OrderItemDateTo Datetime = NULL    -- TODO: change caller to not provide parameter, or leave it to null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- when working with dates try to use an unambiguous format like 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    SET @OrderItemDateFrom = ISNULL(@OrderItemDateFrom, '1970-01-01')
    -- assign a very large date to act like not provided
    -- going one day after to catch DATETIMEs with provided time
    SET @OrderItemDateTo = DATEADD(day, 1, ISNULL(@OrderItemDateTo, '3000-01-01'))

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        COM_OrderItem.OrderItemID, COM_Order.OrderID, 
        COM_Order.OrderDate, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemUnitCount, 
        COM_OrderItem.OrderItemStatus, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUNAME,
        COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUID
    FROM COM_OrderItem
    INNER JOIN COM_Order ON COM_Order.OrderID = COM_OrderItem.OrderItemOrderID
    WHERE COM_Order.OrderCustomerID = @CustomerID 
        OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemWRClass LIKE @OrderItemWRClass + '%' 
        OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUName LIKE @OrderItemSKUName + '%'
        -- between can be used
        OR (COM_OrderDate BETWEEN @OrderItemDateFrom AND @OrderItemDateTo)
    ORDER BY 
        COM_Order.OrderDate DESC
END
```

Another option is to use dynamic SQL and construct it based on parameters values (i.e. insert WHERE condition if filter value is provided). This is particularly useful when filters numbers is relatively low compared to the total number of filters, as `OR`s are not performance friendly.

**NOTE:** shouldn't your filters apply in conjuction (i.e. use AND instead of OR)? It would make sense to allow the user to filter by several value in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CN_GetOrderItemByCustID]
@CustomerID int,
@OrderItemWRClass varchar(max) = NULL,
@OrderItemSKUName varchar(50) = NULL,
@OrderItemDateFrom Datetime,
@OrderItemDateTo Datetime
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF DATEDIFF(d, @OrderItemDateFrom, '01/01/1970') = 0 
   SET @OrderItemDateFrom = null 
IF DATEDIFF(d, @OrderItemDateTo, '01/01/1970') = 0 
   SET @OrderItemDateTo = null 

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT 
    COM_OrderItem.OrderItemID, COM_Order.OrderID, 
    COM_Order.OrderDate, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemUnitCount, 
    COM_OrderItem.OrderItemStatus, COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUNAME,
    COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUID
FROM 
    COM_OrderItem
INNER JOIN 
    COM_Order ON COM_Order.OrderID = COM_OrderItem.OrderItemOrderID
WHERE  
    COM_Order.OrderCustomerID = @CustomerID 
    OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemWRClass LIKE @OrderItemWRClass + '%' 
    OR COM_OrderItem.OrderItemSKUName LIKE @OrderItemSKUName + '%'
    OR (@OrderItemDateFrom IS NULL OR COM_Order.OrderDate >=@OrderItemDateFrom)
    OR (@OrderItemDateTo IS NULL OR COM_Order.OrderDate <=@OrderItemDateTo)
ORDER BY 
    COM_Order.OrderDate DESC
```

You should Try this.

```
OR (@OrderItemDateFrom IS NULL OR COM_Order.OrderDate >=@OrderItemDateFrom)
OR (@OrderItemDateTo IS NULL OR COM_Order.OrderDate <=@OrderItemDateTo)
```

Just Edit and try this condition..